# Windows Service or Windows Form in Background?

Tags: windows, winforms, service, windows-services

In my job, I have to develop a program to read the Firebird files and send them to the Oracle database.

The Firebirds files are in a folder, and the path of this folder is saved in a text file.

The program needs to check whether this text file exists. If it exists, it will read the path of the folder in which the Firebirds files are located. Otherwise, it needs to open a form where the user will select the folder path.

The application will run daily at a certain time.

My question is:

**What is the best way to develop it? A Windows Service or a windows form minimized in the tray?**

Comment: If it has to run when no user is logged on, it has to be a service.  Otherwise, it may as well be a background application, i.e., an application with no visible windows.  That will make it significantly easier to interact with the user.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thanks for answering! In that case, the only advantage of the service is to run without a logged user? I am afraid to use Service because I need to open a screen where the user will indicate the files folder on their first time.

Comment: Hmmm.  Services have a few potential advantages: they can run when no user is logged on; they can run in a different security context than the logged on user; they are easier to track, e.g., by default an entry is placed in the event log when a service stops; and non-administrative users can't kill them.  That's all that occurs to me at the moment.  From what you've said of your scenario, I don't think any of these are likely to be particularly important to you, so it probably isn't worth the difficulty involved in interacting with the user from a service.

Comment: ... if it only takes action once a day, though, you might want to consider a scheduled task rather than a program that sits in the background the entire time.

Comment: Thank you so much, you're helping me a lot. So can I do a program and configure it by the task scheduler to run daily?

Comment: I don't see any reason why not.